# Discord.js bot doesn't correctly recognise user status

Tags: node.js, discord.js

If I make a command like "userstatus" in my discord bot, it doesn't recognise user status correctly, and sends "offline" (even if user is online). How can I fix this?

Here's my code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'status',
    execute(message) {
        message.channel.send(`${message.author.presence.status}`)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while ago, Discord added some privacy guidelines that bot accounts must follow. One of these guidelines was having "Privileged Gateway Intents" [(read more here)](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html). Basically, if you want to track specific user traits, you'll have to enable those features in the Discord Developer Console. The link provided says that if the Gateway Intent is not enabled, all members will appear to be offline, which is what's happening with your code.

In order to enable the Privileged Gateway Intent for tracking presence:

1. Go to [this link](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and login if you need to.
2. Click on your bot and go to the bot section.
3. Scroll down until you see "Privileged Gateway Intents".
4. Enable "Presence Intent" and save changes

After that, you should be able to track user presence.

Comment: You also need to specify the intents you are using, including the privileged intents, when creating the Discord Client, like so: `new Discord.Client({ws: {intents: ["GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILD_PRESENCES"]}})`. And then of course, if using privileged intents, you must also do what you described in this answer. You must do **both** in this scenario, since presences are a privileged intent; doing only one or the other will not work. You can also find a list of all of the intents [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents).